# Need To  Write Program to Decode Alphabet for Secret Message 

Tags: python

So, I need to input a scrambled alphabet, and then input a secret message using that alphabet. My program needs to unscramble the secret message. I have written this so far and am stuck. I was hoping someone could help me. What I tried so far is changing every index in the list to A-Z. My question is how do I use what I wrote for that and make it work for the secret message I input as well.

```
s = ()

alphabet = input("Please input the scrambled alphabet in order: ")
message = input("Now input the scrambled message: ")
alphabet.upper()
s = dict(alphabet)
num = 1

while num < 2:
    s[0] = chr(65)
    s[1] = chr(66)
    s[2] = chr(67)
    s[3] = chr(68)
    s[4] = chr(69)
    s[5] = chr(70)
    s[6] = chr(71)
    s[7] = chr(72)
    s[8] = chr(73)
    s[9] = chr(74)
    s[10] = chr(75)
    s[11] = chr(76)
    s[12] = chr(77)
    s[13] = chr(78)
    s[14] = chr(79)
    s[15] = chr(80)
    s[16] = chr(81)
    s[17] = chr(82)
    s[18] = chr(83)
    s[19] = chr(84)
    s[20] = chr(85)
    s[21] = chr(86)
    s[22] = chr(87)
    s[23] = chr(88)
    s[24] = chr(89)
    s[25] = chr(90)
    num +=1
print (s)

for alpha in message.upper():
    if alpha < "A" or alpha > "Z":
        print(alpha,end="")
    else:
        print(s [ord(alpha) -65 ], end="")
```

Comment: Chris, I didn't downvote you, but you should know that thinking others have read your previous question is very likely not a good assumption. Your titles should be more self-contained and descriptive if you want a good response.

Comment: I think the title is really the only problem with this question (the code has serious problems as well, but otherwise, it shows a solid effort and has a pretty specific question.)

Comment: Thanks Paul -- My previous post had basically the same description, there isn't much to describe its pretty simple. there is just something missing from the code, I was hoping someone could help (it is due in a few hours) and then I would delete both of them.

Comment: That is not the way the site works at all. The Q+A exists largely for the benefit of future users: They aren't supposed to be deleted once they are answered.

Comment: David, do you think you could help me out? I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: I'm composing an answer. But see what I said above: definitely don't plan on deleting anything.

Comment: Understood, I didn't know that was the way this site worked. I won't delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, creating the big dictionary `s` is entirely unnecessary. It literally does nothing: the line:

```
s [ord(alpha) -65 ]
```

Is turning a letter into a number, subtracting 65, and then putting it through a dictionary that adds 65 and turns it back into a number.

Secondly, the line `alphabet.upper()` doesn't actually change the alphabet, it just returns an uppercase version. You need to do

```
alphabet = alphabet.upper()
```

Now for the meaty part. What you meant to do was create a dictionary mapping letters in the code alphabet to letters in the real alphabet. The line `dict(alphabet)` doesn't do this. Instead, iterate through the characters in the string and assign each to the corresponding letter. You're on the right track using `chr`, but are going to way too much work. How about this:

```
s = {}
for i in range(26):  # iterate from 0 to 25
    s[alphabet[i]] = chr(65 + i)
```

since `chr(65 + i)` is the letter in the normal, ordered alphabet, and `alphabet[i]` is the scrambled one.

Once you have that dictionary, running through letter by letter and changing it should be easy (and it's left to you).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the string [`translate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.translate) method:

```
import string

intab   = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' # or string.ascii_lowercase
outtab  = 'xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw'
tab = string.maketrans(intab, outtab)
s = raw_input('Type some text: ').lower()
print s.translate(tab)
```

`maketrans()` creates a table with both alphabets, and `translate()` just replace each character of the string by its pair in the table.

Comment: This is why I love python, the batteries are included!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python - this is pseudocode

> 1. create array of scrambled alphabet
> 2. create array of "normal" alphabet
> 3. foreach char in message, find char in scrambled array, then output corresponding "normal" char

Comment: this is too much. you can just create a single LUT. the array of the normal alphabet isn't needed

Answer (score 0):

You could make a dictionary:

```
alphabet({'a':'alpha', 'b':'bravo','c':'charlie', etc.})
```

so abc would translate to alphabravocharlie

where 'a','b',.. are the coded letters and 'alpha','bravo',... are their actual values.  Make "cypher" by reversing this.

See the section of online tutorials on dictionaries:
http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking 'If I type in a string of characters (I'm assuming a string with no delimiter), how can I make that a dictionary where the first letter = A, the second = B, etc.' (sorry if this is the incorrect interpretation). If that is the case, you could do something like this (note the usage of `raw_input` - `input` is a built-in that evaluates the parameter - it will not assign):

```
alphabet = raw_input("Please input the scrambled alphabet in order: ")
message = raw_input("Now input the scrambled message: ")

secret_map = {}

# Step through the provided string, incrementing the character number by index.
# Index will start at 65 + 0 = A (change to 98 if you want lowercase)
for index, letter in enumerate(alphabet):
    secret_map[letter] = chr(65 + index)

# Now join the string together, mapping each letter to its corresponding value
new_str = ''.join([secret_map[char] for char in message])

# Print the resulting string
print new_str
```

Since this is homework (and perhaps you haven't gotten to list comprehensions), this is equivalent to creating `new_str`:

```
new_str = ''
for letter in message:
    new_str += secret_map[letter]
```

Let me know if this isn't what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I just couldn't resist expanding on stummjr's answer to create a more pythonic version of both encoding and decoding (I added some extra variables to try and make each step more clear):

```
import random, string

cypher_list = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
random.shuffle(cypher_list)
cypher_text = ''.join(cypher_list)

encode_tab = string.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, cypher_text)
decode_tab = string.maketrans(cypher_text, string.ascii_lowercase)

orig_text = 'this means war'
crypt_text = orig_text.translate(encode_tab)
clear_text = crypt_text.translate(decode_tab)

print cypher_text
print crypt_text
print clear_text
assert(clear_text == orig_text)
```